# Cannot send messages to kafka cluster in minishift

Tags: spring-boot, minishift, strimzi

I have a single strimzi kafka cluster running on minishift deployed with default template values. I get no errors when zookeeper starts. The client is a spring boot application but cannot send messages to kafka topic.

These are spring boot application logs:

```
2022-06-20 17:26:13.667  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : 
ConsumerConfig values:
allow.auto.create.topics = true
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = latest
bootstrap.servers =  [http://my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap-kafka.192.168.20.104.nip.io:9092]
check.crcs = true
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = consumer-group_id-1
client.rack = 
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = false
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = group_id
group.instance.id = null
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = []
internal.leave.group.on.close = true
internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 500
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor, class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 45000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
2022-06-20 17:26:13.783  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.1.1
2022-06-20 17:26:13.783  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 97671528ba54a138
2022-06-20 17:26:13.783  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1655745973781
2022-06-20 17:26:13.786  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group_id-1, groupId=group_id] Subscribed to topic(s): my-topic
2022-06-20 17:26:13.833  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-06-20 17:26:13.856  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.sidc.test.kafka.Kafka                : Started Kafka in 2.85 seconds (JVM running for 3.227)
2022-06-20 17:26:23.052  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group_id-1, groupId=group_id] Node -1 disconnected.
2022-06-20 17:26:23.055  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group_id-1, groupId=group_id] Connection to node -1 (my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap-kafka.192.168.20.104.nip.io/192.168.20.104:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-06-20 17:26:23.058  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group_id-1, groupId=group_id] Bootstrap broker my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap-kafka.192.168.20.104.nip.io:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

**Update**

Strimzi default template configuration for zookeeper and kafka cluster

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 2.7.0
    replicas: 1
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1
      log.message.format.version: "2.7"
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "2.7"
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
      - id: 0
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 100Gi
        deleteClaim: false
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 1
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 100Gi
      deleteClaim: false
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

Spring boot application is also deployed on openshift cluster in the same project where kafka is deployed.

Any ideas?

I'm using spring boot 2.7.0

minishift 1.34

strimzi 0.22.1

Comment: You did not shared your `Kafka` custom resource with the Kafka configuration. But if you want to connect from outside, you should probably use an external listener with type `route` which will expose the broker using routes and TLS-SNI. (so you will need to configure also TLS encryption).

Comment: hello @Jakub, thank you for reply, I have updated the question. Also changed the listener type that uses port 9092 to external but got the same result

Comment: Well, the external listener does not seem to be reflected there. But if you use it, you will need to use the port 443 and the correct name of the Route. And you will also need to configure the TLS in your client.

Comment: Could you try it without `http`? Usually this works, but technically it is not the correct protocol and had a problem with this once before.